# Python, Heroku & Memcachier - access settings.py variable

Tags: python, heroku, memcachier

I am following the [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier#python) on Heroku for using Memcahier with Python.

When trying to use the 'mc' variable, which is set in settings.py, in another file I get the following error:

```
    Exception Value:    name 'mc' is not defined
```

I have tried importing settings.py into the file I wish to use the 'mc' variable but I get another error:

```
'Settings' object has no attribute 'mc'
```

How can I access this mc variable outside of the settings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an importing issue.

You need to access `mc` via `settings.mc`, because, provided you imported it using `import settings` at the beginning of the file, it is not included in your current namespace, but in a seperate one called "settings".

If you whish to import it directly into your current namespace, use

```
from settings import *
```

instead.

This only works, when your own file is in the same directory as settings.py, or if settings.py is in a directory known to Python. (See **PYTHONPATH**)

If settings.py is in another Directory, you could for example Import it using the [whole path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692)

It never hurts to skim over the Python docs, by the way: [see this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Also, make sure to use the correct case for your settings module. If the settings file is imported as "settings" with a lowercase letter, then you have to access it like that all over the place, because *Python is case sensitive*

Comment: I had previously tried to access the variable via settings.mc and had the same error as my question.  However using import * has fixed this, thank you !